# How to edit the Reviewer and assignees for already created pull request from the github fork

Tags: github, pull-request, git-fork

I created a pull request from the fork without assigning any reviewer and assignees. Now I want to add reviewer and assignee to the that request. I tried by clicking on 'Edit' but not able to edit the the reviewer and assignee.

Please help me how I can edit.